# Does Thread#join pause all the threads that follows after 'join' statement?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a query in thread join. The Query is whether the thread join means all the threads following after the join will be paused until the thread above it gets completed successfully

In the below code I have placed **one.join after one.start**

```
One one = new One();
Two two = new Two();
Three three = new Three();
Four four = new Four();

one.start();
one.join();  // join placed after one.start
two.start();
three.start();
four.start();
```

and I have got the result as given below which indicates that it blocks two, three and four thread until thread one gets it completed.

> First 0
>   First 1
>   First 2
>   First 3
>   First 4
>   Second 0
>   Third 0
>   Fourth 0
>   Second 1
>   Fourth 1
>   Third 1
>   Second 2
>   Third 2
>   Fourth 2
>   Second 3
>   Fourth 3
>   Third 3
>   Second 4
>   Fourth 4
>   Third 4

Now In the below code I have placed `one.join()` after `two.start()`:

```
One one = new One();
Two two = new Two();
Three three = new Three();
Four four = new Four();

one.start();
two.start();
one.join();  // join placed after two.start
three.start();
four.start();
```

and I have got the result as given below which indicates that it blocks three and four thread until one and two threads got completed.

> First 0
>   Second 0
>   First 1
>   Second 1
>   Second 2
>   First 2
>   Second 3
>   First 3
>   Second 4
>   First 4
>   Fourth 0
>   Third 0
>   Third 1
>   Fourth 1
>   Third 2
>   Fourth 2
>   Third 3
>   Fourth 3
>   Third 4
>   Fourth 4

Comment: No `join` doesn't block other threads, only the thread which called `join`. Your code just can't start the other threads, because your main thread itself is blocked.

Comment: @Tom why then different output when I misplaced the `one.join()`

Comment: I already told you that your main thread will be blocked. So it can perform everything _before_ the `join` call and has to wait until it can execute everything _after_ it.

Comment: so how we can resolve that from main thread blocking

Comment: Resolve what? That the main thread gets blocked? -> Don't call `join`. Or that the others thread won't get started? -> Start them, then call `join`.

Comment: @Tom I'm not getting you....

Answer (score 3):

`t.join()` returns when thread `t` is dead.  It does that, and it establishes a "happens before" relationship, meaning that the caller is guaranteed to be able to see everything that the thread touched in memory after the join() call returns.

That's basically everything that you need to know about `t.join()` in order to correctly use it in Java programs.

---

If you write this:

```
one.start();
one.join();
two.start();
```

The join call doesn't do anything to thread `two`.  In fact, it doesn't do anything to thread `one` either.  It only affects the caller.

Java statements are executed in sequence.  Above, is a sequence of three statements.  `one.start()` starts a thread.  `one.join()` waits for that thread to terminate.  `two.start()` starts another thread.

One statement can't be executed until the previous statement in the sequence is complete.  So, `two.start()` can't be executed until `one.join()` returns, and that won't happen until the `one` thread dies because that's what `one.join()` does:  It waits for the thread to die.